# Running total on calculated column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

[image: 1]

I am using SQL code to get the running total of a column which repeats itself, in my screen shot below, the column `WeightedBilled` is calculated and I use it on the report on group level as `MAX(WeightedColumn)`.

Now I want to add a column that adds the values of `WeightedBilled` and pick up just one value of the said column.

When I use over partition by clause, it adds all repeating values.

My code is:

```
SUM( WeightedBilled) OVER (PARTITION BY(CheckProjID), rpt_tEmployeeName) AS EmpLevelWeightedBill`,
```

On the SSRS 2005 report side: the dark background is where I want the sum of the values.

```
Employee     $2000 (this is what I need here)

Project 1     $500 (displayed as max(weightedBilled))
Project 2     $600 (displayed as max(weightedBilled))
Project 3     $700 (displayed as max(weightedBilled))
Project 4     $200 (displayed as max(weightedBilled))
```

[Report Layout]

[image: 2]

Comment: If you want to gain interest and answers, ideally don't post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, we cannot cut and paste from an image, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) link. A good SQL question will have a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: *"ON SSRS 2005 Report Side"* SSRS 2005? That implies you're also using SQL Server 2005. If you want a running total you'll have to use a triangular JOIN. A better solution would be to use a supported version of SQL Server, not one that hasn't had any support for ~8 years. ***All** supported versions* of SQL Server support cumulative aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

You question is not that clear but assuming you want to add up the max values of a field and also assuming that you have a row group by employee called EmployeeRowGroup then the expression would look like this.

```
=SUM(MAX(Fields!WeightedBilled.Value, "EmployeeRowGroup"))
```

The row group is case sensitive and must be enclosed in double quotes.